# Kotlin Coroutine freezes UI Thread

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, ui-thread, android-anr-dialog

I am executing 40 to 50 coroutines in IO Dispatcher, and all the coroutines are making a network call and saving response DB or shared preference. This leads to UI Freeze and sometimes ANR (Application not responding). Below is the class which I am using for starting each coroutine in parallel.

```
class ParallelBatchExecutor {

private val errorHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
    LSLogger.e("Exception: ${exception.message}", TAG)
}

private var totalItems: Int = 0
private var totalItemsCompleted: Int = 0
private var totalItemsFailed: Int = 0
private lateinit var parentJob: Job
private var childJobs = arrayListOf<Job>()
private val batchProgressMap = hashMapOf<String, BatchProgress>()

fun execute(
    context: Context,
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    batches: List<Batch>,
    batchProgressCallback: BatchProgressCallback
): Job {
    childJobs.clear()
    totalItems += getTotalItemsInBatches(batches)
    parentJob = coroutineScope.launch(errorHandler) {
        startExecution(context, coroutineScope, batches, batchProgressCallback)
    }
    return parentJob
}

private fun startExecution(
    context: Context,
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    batches: List<Batch>,
    batchProgressCallback: BatchProgressCallback
) {
    if (batches.isEmpty()) {
        sendProgressUpdate(batchProgressCallback)
        return
    }
    batches.forEach { batch ->
        if (coroutineScope.isActive) {
            val childJob = coroutineScope.launch(errorHandler) {
                executeBatch(context, batch, batchProgressCallback)
            }
            childJobs.add(childJob)
        }
    }
}

private fun executeBatch(
    context: Context,
    batch: Batch,
    batchProgressCallback: BatchProgressCallback
) {
    batch.execute(context) { batchProgress ->
        processBatchProgress(batchProgress, batchProgressCallback)
    }
}

@Synchronized
private fun processBatchProgress(
    batchProgress: BatchProgress,
    batchProgressCallback: BatchProgressCallback
) {
    if (batchProgress.currentItemSyncStatus) {
        totalItemsCompleted++
    } else {
        totalItemsFailed++
    }
    batchProgressMap[batchProgress.batchId] = batchProgress
    sendProgressUpdate(batchProgressCallback)
}

@Synchronized
private fun sendProgressUpdate(batchProgressCallback: BatchProgressCallback?) {
    if (batchProgressCallback == null) {
        return
    }
    batchProgressCallback.onBatchProgress(
        BatchExecutorProgress(
            Progress(
                totalItems,
                totalItemsCompleted,
                totalItemsFailed
            ), batchProgressMap
        )
    )
}

private fun getTotalItemsInBatches(dataSyncBatches: List<Batch>): Int {
    var totalItemInBatches = 0
    dataSyncBatches.forEach { batch ->
        totalItemInBatches += batch.itemCount
    }
    return totalItemInBatches
}

fun cancel() {
    cancelRunningJob(parentJob)
    cancelChildJobs()
}

fun cancelChildJobs() {
    childJobs.forEach { job ->
        cancelRunningJob(job)
    }
    childJobs.clear()
}

private fun cancelRunningJob(job: Job?) {
    try {
        if (job == null) {
            return
        }
        if (job.isActive) {
            job.cancel()
        }
    } catch (ignore: Exception) {

    }
}

companion object {
    private const val TAG = "MetaDataSyncer"
}}
```

And I am calling the execute function below

```
public void call(){
List<Batch> batches = new SyncBatchBuilder().getSyncBatches(this, mode);
new ParallelBatchExecutor(50).execute(this, Dispatchers.getIO(), batches, progress -> {
// here i am storing the progress to shared preference and sending the boradcast.
})
}
```

I don't know why it freezes the main thread. As I am running all the coroutines in IO thread.

Comment: So something you weren't expecting must either be waiting on the UI thread, or running on the UI thread.  I'd run this, pause it, and see what function the UI thread is running.  Most likely either you launched something on the wrong dispatcher, or you're blocking for the result of something.  I actually think the second is more likely, as I think coroutine continuation goes through the looper and would avoid ANR.

Comment: No we are not waiting result on UI thread. We have added callbacks on every coroutine request. We are starting the coroutines in the IO Dispatcher.

Comment: The only way to get an ANR is for the UI thread to not be returning to the looper.  That means you're either blocking on it, or you're running code on it.  But its more likely to be blocking, because running coroutines should return to the looper.  You're not intending to be blocking.  That doesn't mean you aren't, that's what bugs are- doing something you didn't intend to.  Either way checking where the UI thread is during this block is your best bet.

Comment: We are not able to debug it properly. Can you please recommend some steps to debug this issue?

Comment: What exactly is the use case, don't you think you are making it way more complex then it should be?

Comment: why do you need to pass callbacks to suspending functions, whole point behind a suspending function is to remove the callbacks.

Comment: Maybe the problem comes from shared preferences. Perhaps, you are accessing it in   the ui thread. My advice: Change shared preferences with datastore and look how it performs then.

Comment: I have added the code for my class ParallelBatchExecutor. Please look into it, what's wrong.